# File value is undefined in jQuery click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, all forms are similar to each other, so I want to write one click function to run all.

Following code works fine except files. File value outputs as **undefined**. How can I attach file to this form data?

Here's my click function:

```
$("#save_form").click(
    function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = {};

        $('.form-value').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var value;
            if ($(this).is('select')) {
                value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            } else if ($(this).is(':file')) {
                value = $(this)[0].files[0].value; // Returns undefined.
            } else {
                value = $(this).val();
            }
            formData[id] = value;
        });

        console.log(formData);
```

When I use without value:

```
value = $(this)[0].files[0]
```

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Comment: Which exact operation produces the "Illegal invocation" error?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates?  Taking a step back... Are you just looking for how to upload a file via AJAX with jQuery?  Something else?

Comment: If you're getting an illegal invocation with jQuery's `.ajax`, then add `processData: false, contentType: false` to the options.

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is same thing as `this`....

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved the issue and wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of David and Unmitigated, I solved the issue.

- I send file, not the value.

  ```
  value = $(this)[0].files[0];
  ```
- And than, I added two lines to ajax (processData and contentType as false)

  ```
  method: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  processData: false, 
  contentType: false,
  ```

Comment: `$(this)[0].files[0]` is the same as  `this.files[0]` Know your JavaScript properties.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the file itself. Files do not have a `value` property.

```js
value = this.files[0];
```

To send the `FormData` with `jQuery.ajax`, add the options `processData: false` and `contentType: false` to prevent jQuery from trying to convert the `FormData`.